# Mean Field Theory neglects what flucutations?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, mean-field-theory

This is a topic that has being confusing me for a while. A general phrase that is used in the literature is that:

> Mean Field theories neglect fluctuations

My questions is what is meant by *fluctuations*; spatial or thermal?

To illustrate my confusion let me give two (very predominant) examples of where mean field theory is used.

---

## Example 1: The Ising Model

- The Hamiltonian is given by:
  $$H=-J \sum_{\left<i,j\right>}\sigma_i \sigma_j$$
  where $\sigma_i=\pm 1$.
- We write $\sigma_i=(\sigma_i -M)+M$ and [neglect terms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399740/70392) quadratic in $(\sigma_i-M)$.
- The Partition function is then given by:

$$z=e^{-\beta N z J M^2/2 } \sum_{\{\sigma_i\}}e^{\beta J z M \sum_i \sigma_i}$$

- This can then be solved to find a consistency relation form $M$ which takes the form:
  $$M= \tanh(\beta J z M)$$
- You can proceed to find things like the free energy specific heat etc.

*Here we have clearly not neglected thermal fluctuations and have (at least on the surface) neglected spatial fluctuations by ignoring the quadratic term.*

---

## Example 2: Saddle point approximation

- Here we have a partition function:
  $$ Z=\int \mathscr{D} M(\vec r) e^{-\beta \int d^3 \vec r f[M(\vec r)]}$$
- We find the $M^*(\vec r)$ that minimizes $f[M(\vec r)]$ (which may include derivatives) and then just consider $f[M^*(\vec r)]$ to be the total free energy.

*It should be apparent that this ignores thermal fluctuations (we are ignoring the integral over $M(\vec r)$) but allows for spatial fluctuations - as $M^*$ need not be independent of $\vec r$.*

Comment: In the 1st example, neglecting terms quadratic in $\sigma_{i}-M$ is in some sense neglecting thermal fluctuations -  Those fluctuations are associated with configurations with spin values far from M, so in those configuration, this term is not small.

Comment: Fluctuation is a world which is not very well defined, but what it means is that there are a lot of possible configurations. In any case, having $M^*$ dependent on $r$ does not mean that it is fluctuating... just that it has a spatial dependence (e.g. the mean-field value of the magnetization of an antiferromagnet).